# Pulling results from one function into another function

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, recordset

I am using Access 2010.  How do I get the information in a recordset from one function moved into a different function?  The following code is giving me an object variable not set error:

```
Function Main()
Dim rs as DAO.RecordSet
Dim i as integer

Set rs = QueryResults(i)
   Do While Not rs.EOF
       debug.print rs!result
       rs.MoveNext
   Loop
End Function



Function QueryResults(i as Integer) as DAO.RecordSet
Dim stQuery as String
Dim rsResults as DAO.RecordSet
Dim i2 as Integer

i2 = i
stQuery = "Select query that uses i2 to get results"
Set rsResults = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(stQuery)
End Function
```

I can step through and see that the QueryResults function is working.  I can print out each line from rsResults and see that it has what I want.  The problem comes when the code hits the "do while not rs.EOF" line.  It says that rs was never set to anything.

What am I doing wrong?  Both functions are in the same module.  It seems like it shouldn't be that hard to get results from one function into another function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want a function to return something, you must assign that something to the function name.

Change the last part of your `QueryResults` function to this:

```vb
'Set rsResults = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(stQuery)
Set QueryResults = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(stQuery)
End Function
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  Thank you so much.  I spent way too long looking through websites on how to use recordsets.  I never even noticed the function was never assigned a value.  Thank you for restoring my sanity for the day.